# Data class instance passed by reference instead of by copy

Tags: kotlin

I have a data class:

```
data class User constructor(
    // many other properties here (primatives, references to other data classes and lists)
    var isPrivate: Boolean = false,
)
```

I also have two functions:

```
private fun updateUser(oldUser: User, newUser: User) {
    if(doSomething(oldUser, newUser))
        Log.d("TAG", newUser.toString)
    // other things here
}

private fun doSomething(oldUser: User, newUser: User) {
    newUser.isPrivate = !newUser.isPrivate
    // other things here
}
```

The problem I encountered is that when the property `isPrivate` in `doSomething()` is changed, this property is also changing in the `updateUser()`.

Could you explain to me why this property has changed in the outer function also? I always thought that when i pass an object as an argument, it is passed by copy but here it seems like it is passed by reference.

Comment: Objects are passed by references primitives by copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newUser` is an object that represents some data, and you're changing the data it holds. You're passing that object around, so if you change that data it will be changed everywhere, because it's the same instance.

If you don't want `newUser`'s `isPrivate` value to change, why are you changing it? Can't you just put that value in a local variable, and use that for whatever the rest of the function is doing?

If you need a temporary version of that object to do stuff with, you can use `newUser.copy()` - this is sort of what data classes are designed for, and you can specify values you want to change on the new version while you're copying it: `newUser.copy(isPrivate = !newUser.isPrivate)` and so on. This copying functionality lets you make your data class properties `val`s instead of `var`s, meaning they can be immutable, but you can still "change" them by getting a new version with the changes you want.

Answer (score 2):

Objects of any kind are always passed by reference.
If you want a new object you can call `newUser.copy()`, you could use that at the call site like:

```kotlin
doSomething(oldUser, newUser.copy())
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when you pass a value type argument to a function, it copies the value, and it does not change the value in other function. Even though *isPrivate* here is a **boolean** which is a **value type**, it is a property in the **User** class which is the **reference type**. Both functions accept User parameter, so changing the *isPrivate* value in the object will reflect to all functions that you passed the User object to.

Comment: So how can I ensure that all there are not references? Can i specify it somehow in a function's declaration or do I have to create a copy of some sort every time i have to change something?

Comment: You have to copy it manually every time. Unfortunately, Kotlin doesn’t have structs.